# OnClick Send To Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to complete some ajax requests to insert a textarea into a database without refresh. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<textarea name='Status'> </textarea>
<input type='button' onclick='UpdateStatus()' value='Status Update'>
```

JS:

```
function UpdateStatus(Status)
    {
    var Status = $(this).val();

        $(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Ajax/StatusUpdate.php?Status='.Status, data: "", dataType: 'json'
            });

        });
    }
```

My Questions:

1) How do I send the contents of the text area into the onclick function?

2) How do I escape/urlencode etc.. So it retains line breaks

Comment: first `.` should be `+` in `url:'Ajax/StatusUpdate.php?Status='.Status, data: "", dataType: 'json'` because its javascript not PHP.

Comment: everybody please put reason of -1 to do something useful.

Comment: @imsiso And secondly?

Comment: secondly whats yuor second question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<textarea name='Status'> </textarea>
<input type='button' value='Status Update'>
```

You have few problems with your code like using `.` for concatenation

Try this -

```
$(function () {
    $('input').on('click', function () {
        var Status = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Ajax/StatusUpdate.php',
            data: {
                text: $("textarea[name=Status]").val(),
                Status: Status
            },
            dataType : 'json'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This inputs "Status Update" which is the name of the button into my database columns where the text area content should be

Comment: Looking for $_GET['Status'];

Comment: In this case you need `$_GET['text']`

Comment: @SophieMackeral .. As Philipp already mentioned.. You can get textarea content with `$_GET['text']` and Status with `$_GET['Status']`

Answer (score 3):

Tried and working. you are using,

```js
<textarea name='Status'> </textarea>
<input type='button' onclick='UpdateStatus()' value='Status Update'>
```

I am using javascript, (don't know about php), use `id="status"` in textarea like

```js
<textarea name='Status' id="status"> </textarea>
<input type='button' onclick='UpdateStatus()' value='Status Update'>
```

then make a call to servlet sending the status to backend for updating using whatever structure (like MVC in java or any other) you like, like this in your UI in script tag

```js
<script>
function UpdateStatus(){
    
    //make an ajax call and get status value using the same 'id'
    var var1= document.getElementById("status").value;
    $.ajax({
        
            type:"GET",//or POST
            url:'http://localhost:7080/ajaxforjson/Testajax',
                               //  (or whatever your url is)
            data:{data1:var1},
            //can send multipledata like {data1:var1,data2:var2,data3:var3
            //can use dataType:'text/html' or 'json' if response type expected 
            success:function(responsedata){
                   // process on data
                   alert("got response as "+"'"+responsedata+"'");
            }
         })
}
</script>
```

and jsp is like the servlet will look like:

```java
//webservlet("/zcvdzv") is just for url annotation
@WebServlet("/Testajax")
    
public class Testajax extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Testajax() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data1=request.getParameter("data1");
        //do processing on datas pass in other java class to add to DB
        // i am adding or concatenate
        String data="i Got : "+"'"+data1+"' ";
        System.out.println(" data1 : "+data1+"\n data "+data);
        response.getWriter().write(data);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```