# How to call a on click button on PHP

Tags: php, html, css

So I have been working on this project of a learning site.So there are teachers and students and different subjects. So I have separated the teacher and student registration page because they go in different tables in the database. I already have a landing page and when someone clicks to register as a teacher they will see a bunch of subjects that they can choose. So I need the code to call one of those buttons in the PHP code so I can redirect them on other pages.This is what the buttons look like:

```
<a href="technology_sign-up.php" class="tech-s-u" style="text-decoration:none; text-align: center; padding-left: 20px;">
    <button style="cursor:pointer;border: none; background-color: dodgerblue; border-radius: 5px;"><h1 style="color: white; font-family: Patua One;">
        Technology
        </h1>
    </button>
</a>
```

Basically i need to create a function and i need to call this button as a variable and then use it.
If I should do it with AJAX please give more explanation because I don't understand AJAX that well. 
Excuse me for if my explain isn't completely understandable!
I am new to PHP.
Thank you!!

Comment: Well use google first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754246/onclick-send-to-ajax

Comment: You can include a script in your page that uses [**JavaScript addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to bind the click event to the button and then redirect them using [**Window location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) OR if you are using jQuery you can can use [**jQuery on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the click event and then still use `window.location.href = targetUrl;`

Comment: Fran thanks mate! I'll try and see if it works!

Answer (score 1):

What is Ajax ?

Ajax is a way to make a request be a remote call or local file call. It happens **asynchronously** which means that the page does not refreshes while the data gets load.

For ex : Imagine a page in which there are 3 menu links **home**,**aboutus**,**contact**. Typically when you click on a link the page will refresh to load the content. By using AJAX you can load the content dynamically without reloading the page.

There are different ways to write ajax calls.

**Ex :**

```
function yourfunc() {
    $.ajax ({
        type:"post",
        url: "yoururl",
        data:data,
        success:function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```

This is a jquery ajax example. You can check this link [Ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

**HTML :**

```
<button onclick="yourfunc()">Click</button>
```

[Reference link how ajax works](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the help sir!!